# laravel resource change the id when get data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-5.3

i am using the resource in laravel when I get the data its ask me for the id but the primary key in my table is user_menu_id how to change the using resource route

route

```
Route::resource('/UserMenuController', 'UserMenuController');
```

error

> Unknown column 'user_menus.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from 
>       `user_menus` where `user_menus`.`id` = 1 limit 1)

[image]
model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class user_menu extends Model
{

 protected $fillable = ['menu_parent_id', 'menu_title', 'menu_class', 
'menu_id', 'menu_link', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://medium.com/@petehouston/laravel-fact-override-eloquent-default-primary-key-properties-f6a9d1990ffc), you need to override `$primaryKey` property:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class user_menu extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'menu_parent_id', 'menu_title', 'menu_class', 
        'menu_id', 'menu_link', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'created_at', 'updated_at'
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_menu_id';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says there is not a table with named `user_menus`. Set the real table name `$table` property in the model:

```
protected $table = 'user_menu';
```

Or you may [follow Laravel naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions) as described in my repo and just rename the table to `user_menus` (plural for `user_menu` class).

You said the primary key is not standard too, so change it too to `$primaryKey`:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_menu_id';
```

Comment: in my table primary key name is user_menu_id but it asking for id i need to change that id

Comment: Ok, then my original answer was correct, just add `$primaryKey`. Also, is the table name `user_menu` or `user_menus`?

Answer (score 1):

Define the primary key in your model class and you will be golden.

The reason you're encountering an error is due Laravel always assuming the primary key is `id`. Reading the error log, you will notice:

`1054 Unknown column 'user_menus.id'` - you can right away know it's trying to find a non-existent column.

The fix will is to assign `$primaryKey` to your model class, e.g:

`protected $primaryKey = 'user_menu_id';`

Comment: Sorry, OP just said the primary key is not `id`, so the answer is correct. Upvoted.

Answer (score -1):

**Eloquent** will assume that each table has a primary key column named `id`. You may define a protected `$primaryKey` property to override this convention.

```
class user_menu extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_menu_id';
}
```